# How do I test Nginx using server_name on localhost?

Tags: nginx

I have some nginx directives containing server_name. I want to test my config on localhost.

I thought all I would need to do is to spoof the HTTP host header (using tamperdata firefox extension) but that doesn't seem to be working correctly (I'm getting hits on the wrong handler, not sure if my config is broken or my testing method).

What is the correct way to test locally?

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that you need to add the following lines to /etc/hosts on your computer (%WindowsDir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts for Windows, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29 fore more):

127.0.0.1 domain.tld www.domain.tld domain2.tld www.domain2.tld

Comment: I'd like to be able to simultaneously access the production host. Is there really no other way?

Comment: In any case editing /etc/hosts doesn't seem to have any impact on DNS lookups on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: @user492922 it should, maybe the page is cached, try ctrl+f5, or a different browser, or private browsing.